# Ansible: "sudo: a password is required\r\n"

Tags: ssh, ansible

quick question

I have setup an Ubuntu server with a user named test. I copy the authorized_keys to it, I can ssh no problem.
If I do **$ ansible -m ping ubu1**, no problem  I get a response

```
    <i><p>ubu1 | SUCCESS => {
        <br>"changed": false, 
        <br>"ping": "pong"
    <br>}</i>
```

What I dont get is this, If I do

**$ ansible-playbook -vvvv Playbooks/htopInstall.yml**

```
fatal: [ubu1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "setup"}, "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 6109\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\nShared connection to 192.168.1.112 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

If I do **$ ansible-playbook --ask-sudo-pass Playbooks/htopInstall.yml**, then it ask my user password and the play is a success.

If I rename the authorized_keys it tells me I "Failed to connect to the host via ssh." which is ok.
What I dont understand is why is it asking for a sudo password. I definetly missed something along the way.

my **ansible.cfg** file looks like this

```
[defaults]
nocows = 1
inventory = ./Playbooks/hosts
remote_user = test
private_key_file = /home/test/.ssh/id_ubu
host_key_checking = false
```

my hosts file looks like this

```
[servers]
ubu1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.112 ansible_ssh_user=test
```

Comment: You have not included the most important file `Playbooks/htopInstall.yml`. And please spend a few minutes on learning how formatting works on SO and what formatting is commonly used for different elements.

Comment: Do you have passwordless sudo enabled on target host for your `test` user?

Answer (score 18):

> What I dont understand is why is it asking for a sudo password.

We can't say for certain without seeing your playbook, but it's almost certainly because a) your playbook asks Ansible to run a particular command with `sudo` (via the `sudo` or `become` directives) and b) the `test` user does not have password-less sudo enabled.

It sounds like you are aware of (a) but are confused about (b); specifically, what I'm picking up is that you don't understand the difference between *ssh authentication* and *sudo authentication*.  Again, without more information I can't confirm if this is the case, but I'll take a stab at explaining it in case I guessed correctly.

When you connect to a machine via ssh, there are two primary ways in which sshd authenticates you and allows you to log in as a particular user.  The first is to ask for the account's password, which is hands off to the system, and allows a login if it was correct.  The second is through [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), in which you prove that you have access to a private key that corresponds to a public key fingerprint in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Passing sshd's authentication checks gives you a shell on the machine.

When you invoke a command with `sudo`, you're asking `sudo` to elevate your privileges beyond what the account normally gets.  This is an entirely different system, with rules defined in `/etc/sudoers` (which you should edit using `sudo visudo`) that control which users are allowed to use sudo, what commands they should be able to run, whether they need to re-enter their password or not when using the command, and a variety of other configuration options.

When you run the playbook normally, Ansible is presented with a sudo prompt and doesn't know how to continue - it doesn't know the account password.  That's why `--ask-sudo-pass` exists: you're giving the password to Ansible so that it can pass it on to sudo when prompted.  If you don't want to have to type this every time and you've decided it's within your security parameters to allow anyone logged in as the `test` user to perform any action as root, then you can consult `man sudoers` on how to set passwordless sudo for that account.

Comment: I'm not sure if --as-sudo-pass is version dependent... but it works for me when I use --ask-become-pass or simply the equivalent -K.

Comment: @RichardGomes As the project aimed more at non-Linux uses, it shifted to the "become" terminology (which delegates to sudo or other privilege escalation systems); for a while they were both there, but I guess they finally removed the options with "sudo".  They are functionally equivalent on a system with sudo, though.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this exact error `sudo: a password is required\n` which I got when running my playbook with `become: true` but somewhere in a task delegating to localhost, something like this:

```
uri:
  url: "{{ some_url }}"
  return_content: yes
  status_code: 200
delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

If I understood correctly, the `become: true` causes Ansible to log into the remote host as my user and then use `sudo` in order to execute all commands on the remote host as `root`. Now when delegating to `127.0.0.1`, `sudo` is also executed and as it happens that on my localhost a password is expected when using `sudo`.

For me the solution was simply to remove the `delegate_to`, which was not actually needed in that particular use case.